# How can I clear browser's cache?

Tags: caching, browser

I have a problem with cache. When I visit my site I see the old topic until I hit ctl+f5 to update the page. Is there any way to prevent browser from storing cache?

I have used these meta:

```
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">
```

but same result

Comment: If you're using firefox for your tests, you can always do "private browsing". For IE it's "InPrivate browsing". Opera "Private Tab". Adding headers explicitly is hindering performance and consuming user's bandwidth unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following headers :

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
```

More can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers)

**Edit1:** As mentioned further in the link, use these plain HTML tags between `<head>` and `</head>` and see if it works :

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

Comment: where i put them between <head>here ? </head>

Comment: after using the code i get the same result, how can i use the first code 'php' not 'html'

Comment: First you have to make sure php is installed on the server/machine. Then enclose the first php code inside `<?php` and `?>` tags and save the file as **abc.php** instead of **abc.html**

Comment: right now i am working on the server and when i but the code between <body></body> i get this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in C:\AppServ\www\d\index.php on line 59

Comment: sorry i want to say before i work on my site on the server i try it on localhost is it will the cause of this problem